# return 0 when empty result sql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Can i return 0 as an result when there is an empty resultset

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`Uren`),
  SUM(`Minuten`) 
FROM
  `Uren` 
  RIGHT JOIN `Project` 
    ON `Project`.`idProject` = `Uren`.`idProject` 
  RIGHT JOIN `Uursoort` 
    ON `Uursoort`.`idUursoort` = `Uren`.`idUursoort` 
WHERE `idKlant` = 5 
  AND `Uren`.`Datum` > '2014-04-02' 
GROUP BY `Uren`.`idProject`
```

Prefered output (instead of empty resultset):

```
sum('Uren')     sum('Minuten')
0               0
```

when i do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`Uren`),
  SUM(`Minuten`) 
FROM
  `Uren` 
  RIGHT JOIN `Project` 
    ON `Project`.`idProject` = `Uren`.`idProject` 
  RIGHT JOIN `Uursoort` 
    ON `Uursoort`.`idUursoort` = `Uren`.`idUursoort` 
WHERE `idKlant` = 5 
  AND `Uren`.`Datum` > '2014-04-02' 
GROUP BY `Uren`.`idProject
```

i get right output because there is data. But i need to get 0 as an return. 
i also tried this in the model:

```
    function rapport_detail_uren($idKlant,$start,$eind){
            $this->db->select_sum('Uren');
            $this->db->select_sum('Minuten');
            $this->db->from('Uren');
            $this->db->join('Uursoort','Uursoort.idUursoort=Uren.idUursoort','right');
            $this->db->join('Project','Project.idProject=Uren.idProject','right');
            if ($idKlant > 0){
            $this->db->where('idKlant',$idKlant);}  
if ($start != NULL){
        $this->db->where('Uren.Datum >=', $start);
        }

            $this->db->group_by('Uren.idProject');

            $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
                return $query->result();
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
    }
```

the last line return 0. i thought maybe this will return the value's as 0 but that doesnt work

Comment: The statement looks wrong to me. You group by idProject, but it's not in the result columns. So you get, say ten result records with some counts, but don't know what project id these numbers are related to? Then you outer join, so you even select projects without an Uren record, but then you say you only want Uren records with a certain date, thus elimiating the outer joined records again. And your question is: The statement results in zero to many records; in case there is zero records, how to show a record with zeroes instead of no records? Yes?

Comment: @Rene: Again: You sometimes get one row, sometimes two, sometimes more and sometimes none. Instead of none you want a row with zeros. Is this right? Is this your request?

Comment: Yes indeed that is my request @Ravinder i tried this but still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by moving the `where` conditions into the `on` clause for all tables except the last one (because you are using `right outer join`:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(`Uren`), 0), coalesce(SUM(`Minuten`), 0)
FROM `Uren` RIGHT JOIN
     `Project` 
      ON `Project`.`idProject` = `Uren`.`idProject` AND
         `Uren`.`Datum` > '2014-04-02' RIGHT JOIN
     `Uursoort` 
      ON `Uursoort`.`idUursoort` = `Uren`.`idUursoort` 
WHERE `idKlant` = 5 AND 
GROUP BY `Uren`.`idProject`;
```

Personally, I find `left outer join` easier to follow ("Keep all the rows in the first table" versus "keep all the rows in the last table"), but the same principle applies:  `where` conditions can turn outer joins into inner joins because outer joins generate unexpected `NULL` values.

You might also have to move `idklant` to an `on` clause.  And I question why you are aggregating by `uren.idProject`, which might have `NULL` values.

Comment: STill i get the same return.:(

Answer (score 0):

Do this with your SUMs:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Uren),0),IFNULL(SUM(Minuten),0)
```

I have also had to do this, but with DB2 and DB2 is not standardized, to solve this same problem.

```
SELECT 0,0
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Uren), SUM(Minuten)
```

Comment: That still returns the same:( (empty results)

Comment: How about SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Uren),0),COALESCE(SUM(Minuten),0)

Comment: Thats the same answer as gordon linoff but that doesnt work somehow:( i  just dont get a NULL

Comment: Basically, you always want to do what Gordon suggests, so I would look at the Right Outer Join.

Comment: i have done this but still it gets no rows returned. if no 0's or something like that

Answer (score 0):

**This should be working**:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( `Uren` ) AS SUM_Uren,
  SUM( `Minuten` ) AS SUM_Minuten
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    `Uren`.`idProject
    IF( count( `Uren` ) > 0, `Uren`, 0 ) AS `Uren`,
    IF( count( `Minuten` ) > 0, `Minuten`, 0 ) AS `Minuten`
  FROM `Uren` 
    RIGHT JOIN `Project` 
            ON `Project`.`idProject` = `Uren`.`idProject` 
    RIGHT JOIN `Uursoort` 
            ON `Uursoort`.`idUursoort` = `Uren`.`idUursoort` 
  WHERE `idKlant` = 5 
    AND `Uren`.`Datum` > '2014-04-02' 
) results
GROUP BY `idProject`
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not easily done. (Or at least it gets awkward.) Your select statement returns zero, one or more rows. In case it returns none, you want a row generated. So you must execute your statement twice; once for the normal rows and once to determine wether you need to create an addidtional row:

```
select col1, col2 -- <= your statement 
from some tables
where some criteria
UNION ALL -- Add ...
select 0, 0 -- ... a record containing zeros, but ...
where not exists -- ... due to this clause only when your query returns no records.
(
  select col1, col2  -- <= your statement again
  from some tables
  where some criteria
);
```

Just copy and paste your own statement (which I still consider dubious btw).